# Fetching JSON which might contain null values

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am trying to fetch data using JSON via google script. For the condition given below full data is Parsed JSON Response. The object "tags" need to be stored in a cell. The tag is empty in this case ( JSON: `tags: null`) so if statement should be sufficient in this case but I am getting an error Cannot read property 'length' of null (line 4, file "Code"). Any solution around this because there can be many empty cells while getting the data using API

```
var f3 = fullData.tags 
      var valar3 = "";
      if (f3 = null) {currentSheet.getRange(i+2,21).setValue("")}
      else {for (var b=0; b<fullData.tags.length; b++){
        var val = fullData.specificExams[b];
        valar3 += val + ",";}}
      valar3 = valar3.substring(0, valar3.length - 1);
      currentSheet.getRange(i+2,21).setValue(valar3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong `if (f3 = null)`. It should be `if (f3 == null)` or `if(!f3)`